# how to specify dtype when importing csv so that the first column is the index and is parsed as a date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, indexing

I have tried both:

```
prices = pd.read_csv("/Users/Joshua/Documents/asx_data/asx_historical_price_data.csv",index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
```

Where Prices.index ends up of int datatype and not datetime index

and...

```
dtypes = [float, float, float,float,float,float,str,str,str,str] 
prices = pd.read_csv("/Users/Joshua/Documents/asx_data/asx_historical_price_data.csv",index_col=0,dtype=dtypes)
```

Here when I specify the datatype for all columns I have tried using datetime, and datetime.datetime for the index column, as well as leaving out the datatype for col_0 because I already set it to the index with index_col.

What is the correct way to specify datatypes for importing a csv file when you want the first column to be the index and have a datetime datatype?

Comment: This is a bug, you have to either set the index after specifying the dtype or set the index and then change the dtype after `read_csv`

Comment: @EdChum thanks, I will do that, how do I set the "date" column to be a datetime if I use the dtype= option? for read_csv?

Comment: for me datetime, and datetime.datetime throw errors when I use dtype=dtypes? and [datetime or datetime.datetime, float, float, float,float,float,float,str,str,str,str]

Comment: set `parse_dates=[0]` or whatever the name/ordinal position of the col is, there is an issue on github somewhere

Comment: ok, and if I instead use the set_index after importing the csv (as compared to parse_dates=[0] then can I use the dtypes option on the read of the csv? How do I correctly write the statement to import a column as dates?

Comment: IIUC then you need to set the first dtype to `np.datetime64` but you can't pass `index_col=0` if you do that

Comment: @EdChum thanks but when I use np.datetime64 I get the error datatype not understood. Is there anything I need to be doing to avoid this? dtypes = [np.datetime64, float, float, float,float,float,float,str,str,str,str],

Comment: Have you imported numpy? Import numpy as np

Comment: @EdChum yes I have imported numpy however it still gives me the error datatype not understood

Comment: OK, having looked at this you can't do it using `dtype` param, you have to use `parse_dates` and pass either the ordinal position or the name of the col

Answer (score 0):

Use `dtype` as you would normally (I'd suggest using a dictionary instead of list if you can, less error prone, read the section in [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html))

Use `index_col =[0]` to tell it to use set the "0th" column as the index and then use `parse_dates=[0]` to tell it to parse that column as a date.

Example: 
`pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype={<insert dtypes>}, index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)`

Note: Unfortunately [`format`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) does not seem to be implemented in the `read_csv` yet, you might get away with it by using `infer_datetime_format=True`

Extra note: This answer was 95% given by [@EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) in the comments, so I'd suggest he answer it and take the credit